# roof or drylining walls first

Tags: building

We are renovating our house, re-roofing, dry lining and getting windows replaced.  The builder recons he will do the dry lining first and then the roof . Does it matter in what order this happens

Comment: By dry lining, you mean adding drywall?

Answer (score 1):

Well, does your roof leak now? If it leaks and they put in new drywall, and it rains, the new drywall could get leaked on & possibly ruined.

Even if the roof doesn't leak now, they have to tear off the old roof to put a new one on, and they *really should* wait for good dry weather to do that but sometimes they don't, or unexpected storms appear. So without a roof you almost certainly will have leaks inside the house, again possibly ruining new drywall.

So, with good weather it shouldn't matter. But if it rains & leaks, it will matter. Why not do the roof first?